# Changing order of dummy variable output in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, categorical-data

I've run a linear regression model for a continuous dependent variable on a categorical independent variable with 10 levels. I've set the reference group for the categorical variable to the level with the highest mean for the dependent variable.

However, the order of the dummy variables in the regression output is random and therefore it is harder to interpret which displays higher/lower coefficients. Is there a way that I could view the dummy variables in order of coefficient value? So that essentially the output displays dummy variables from highest to lowest coefficient value?

Comment: Hey @SoniaG you can find an answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416943/sorting-the-coefficients-table-of-a-stepaic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting the "Coefficients" table of a StepAIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416943/sorting-the-coefficients-table-of-a-stepaic)